# Qt system tray application can't receive the WM_QUERYENDSESSION or WM_ENDSESSION message

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I'm new and have coded something like this:

```
class MyXcbEventFilter : public QAbstractNativeEventFilter
{
public:
MyXcbEventFilter():myWindow(Q_NULLPTR)
{}
void setMainWindow(QMainWindow* _mainWindow){
    myWindow=_mainWindow;
}

virtual bool nativeEventFilter(const QByteArray &eventType, void *message, long *) Q_DECL_OVERRIDE
{
        MSG * pMsg = static_cast<MSG *>(message);
        if (WM_ENDSESSION==pMsg->message||WM_QUERYENDSESSION==pMsg->message)
        {
            QSound::play(":/Sound/start.wav");
            if(myWindow!=Q_NULLPTR){
                myWindow->close();
            }
        }
    return false;
}
private:
QMainWindow* myWindow;
};
```

What I want to do is detect system shutdown and do some cleanup.

The code works normally when the app windows is maximized but not work when the app window is minimized to system tray.

What's wrong?

The platform is: windows 10 64，Qt 5.7.1，MSVC2015

Comment: How long does it take to play that sound file? The amount of time you have to respond to these messages is shorter if the application has _"no visible top-level window and no reason string specified"_. [Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms700677%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Comment: thank you for reply. the "start.wav" is about 1 second long. if i make the app window shows on desktop, the start.wav played and myWindow->close() run ok.

Answer (score 0):

It is a Windows/Qt cooperation issue (if not directly a Qt bug). Likely it worked in Qt4 and/or earlier Windows versions. A workaround is to always have an invisible window:

```
// Don't let this run out of scope before end of app exec
// As long as this invisible widget is 'shown' messages will be recieved in eventfilter
QWidget wdg; 
wdg.setWindowFlags(Qt::FramelessWindowHint | Qt::WindowStaysOnBottomHint);
wdg.setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground, true);
wdg.show();
wdg.setFixedSize(0, 0);
```